# How find the maxima of a uniformly convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $f_n: D_{z_0,r} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of continuous functions such that the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 
|f_n(z)|
$$
is uniformly convergent on $D_{z_0,r}$ a complex disk of center $z_0$ and radius r.
How can I find the maxima of that series?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "find"?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli any information about point where the series have the global maxima

Comment: Virtually anywhere. For instance, you can find a series of positive $C^\infty$ functions $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N} f_n$ which converges uniformly to a $C^\infty$ function $g\le1$ which takes the value $1$ on a closed subset of your choosing.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli if $f_n$ are holomorphic functions is it true that tha maxima is on the  boundary

Comment: That's because being holomorphic is stronger than being a $C^\infty$ function in the real variables of $D_{z_0,r}$ (and hilariously stronger than continuity).

Comment: Another thing you can do is write the Cantor staircase function $c$ as a normally convergent series $\sum c_n$ and consider $c\left(\left\lvert \frac{z-z_0}r\right\rvert\right)$. Its local maxima are a dense open subset.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thanks for suggestion